# Get li ID in a nested list created by nestable.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-nestable

I'm using Nestable.js plugin. I'm wondering how can I get access to the li element I'm clicking on. I'm trying to do it with the code below, but nothing is happening.

```
$('.dd-item').on('change', function(Event) {
        console.log(Event.target);
    });

    $('.dd-item').on('click', function(Event) {
        console.log(Event.target);
    });
```

If someone could take a look at it, I left all the files I'm using below. The code above is inserted in the HTML one.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appearance.css"></link>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="dd">
    <ul class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="apples">
            <div class="dd-handle">Apples</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item"  data-id="oranges">
            <div class="dd-handle">Oranges</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="bananas">
            <div class="dd-handle">Bananas</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="strawberries">
             <div class="dd-handle">Strawberries</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div>
            <ul class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="5">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 5</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>


    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="nestable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dd').nestable('');

    $('.dd-item').on('change', function(Event) {
        console.log(Event.target);
    });

    $('.dd-item').on('click', function(Event) {
        console.log(Event.target);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.cf:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }
* html .cf { zoom: 1; }
*:first-child+html .cf { zoom: 1; }

/*NESTABLE*/
.dd { position: relative; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; max-width: 600px; list-style: none; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px; }

.dd-list { display: block; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.dd-list .dd-list { padding-left: 30px; }
.dd-collapsed .dd-list { display: none; }

.dd-item,
.dd-empty,
.dd-placeholder { display: block; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height: 20px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px; }

.dd-handle { display: block; height: 30px; margin: 5px 0; padding: 5px 10px; color: #333; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fafafa;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 0%, #eee 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 0%, #eee 100%);
    background:         linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 0%, #eee 100%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dd-handle:hover { color: #2ea8e5; background: #fff; }

.dd-item > button { display: block; position: relative; cursor: pointer; float: left; width: 25px; height: 20px; margin: 5px 0; padding: 0; text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; border: 0; background: transparent; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; }
.dd-item > button:before { content: '+'; display: block; position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align: center; text-indent: 0; }
.dd-item > button[data-action="collapse"]:before { content: '-'; }
.button_make_container > .dd_item

.dd-placeholder,
.dd-empty { margin: 5px 0; padding: 0; min-height: 30px; background: #f2fbff; border: 1px dashed #b6bcbf; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; }
.dd-empty { border: 1px dashed #bbb; min-height: 100px; background-color: #e5e5e5;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff),
                         -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff),
                              linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff);
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px;
}

.dd-dragel { position: absolute; pointer-events: none; z-index: 9999; }
.dd-dragel > .dd-item .dd-handle { margin-top: 0; }
.dd-dragel .dd-handle {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            box-shadow: 2px 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

#button_make_container {
   border: 1px outset blue;
   background-color: lightBlue;
   float: right;
}
```

And here is nestable:

```
/*!
 * Nestable jQuery Plugin - Copyright (c) 2012 David Bushell - http://dbushell.com/
 * Dual-licensed under the BSD or MIT licenses
 */
;(function($, window, document, undefined)
{
    var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document;

    /**
     * Detect CSS pointer-events property
     * events are normally disabled on the dragging element to avoid conflicts
     * https://github.com/ausi/Feature-detection-technique-for-pointer-events/blob/master/modernizr-pointerevents.js
     */
    var hasPointerEvents = (function()
    {
        var el    = document.createElement('div'),
            docEl = document.documentElement;
        if (!('pointerEvents' in el.style)) {
            return false;
        }
        el.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
        el.style.pointerEvents = 'x';
        docEl.appendChild(el);
        var supports = window.getComputedStyle && window.getComputedStyle(el, '').pointerEvents === 'auto';
        docEl.removeChild(el);
        return !!supports;
    })();

    var defaults = {
            listNodeName    : 'ol',
            itemNodeName    : 'li',
            rootClass       : 'dd',
            listClass       : 'dd-list',
            itemClass       : 'dd-item',
            dragClass       : 'dd-dragel',
            handleClass     : 'dd-handle',
            collapsedClass  : 'dd-collapsed',
            placeClass      : 'dd-placeholder',
            noDragClass     : 'dd-nodrag',
            emptyClass      : 'dd-empty',
            expandBtnHTML   : '<button data-action="expand" type="button">Expand</button>',
            collapseBtnHTML : '<button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>',
            group           : 0,
            maxDepth        : 5,
            threshold       : 20
        };

    function Plugin(element, options)
    {
        this.w  = $(document);
        this.el = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function()
        {
            var list = this;

            list.reset();

            list.el.data('nestable-group', this.options.group);

            list.placeEl = $('<div class="' + list.options.placeClass + '"/>');

            $.each(this.el.find(list.options.itemNodeName), function(k, el) {
                list.setParent($(el));
            });

            list.el.on('click', 'button', function(e) {
                if (list.dragEl) {
                    return;
                }
                var target = $(e.currentTarget),
                    action = target.data('action'),
                    item   = target.parent(list.options.itemNodeName);
                if (action === 'collapse') {
                    list.collapseItem(item);
                }
                if (action === 'expand') {
                    list.expandItem(item);
                }
            });

            var onStartEvent = function(e)
            {
                var handle = $(e.target);
                if (!handle.hasClass(list.options.handleClass)) {
                    if (handle.closest('.' + list.options.noDragClass).length) {
                        return;
                    }
                    handle = handle.closest('.' + list.options.handleClass);
                }

                if (!handle.length || list.dragEl) {
                    return;
                }

                list.isTouch = /^touch/.test(e.type);
                if (list.isTouch && e.touches.length !== 1) {
                    return;
                }

                e.preventDefault();
                list.dragStart(e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e);
            };

            var onMoveEvent = function(e)
            {
                if (list.dragEl) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    list.dragMove(e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e);
                }
            };

            var onEndEvent = function(e)
            {
                if (list.dragEl) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    list.dragStop(e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e);
                }
            };

            if (hasTouch) {
                list.el[0].addEventListener('touchstart', onStartEvent, false);
                window.addEventListener('touchmove', onMoveEvent, false);
                window.addEventListener('touchend', onEndEvent, false);
                window.addEventListener('touchcancel', onEndEvent, false);
            }

            list.el.on('mousedown', onStartEvent);
            list.w.on('mousemove', onMoveEvent);
            list.w.on('mouseup', onEndEvent);

            console.log(list);

        },

        serialize: function()
        {
            var data,
                depth = 0,
                list  = this;
                step  = function(level, depth)
                {
                    var array = [ ],
                        items = level.children(list.options.itemNodeName);
                    items.each(function()
                    {
                        var li   = $(this),
                            item = $.extend({}, li.data()),
                            sub  = li.children(list.options.listNodeName);
                        if (sub.length) {
                            item.children = step(sub, depth + 1);
                        }
                        array.push(item);
                    });
                    return array;
                };
            data = step(list.el.find(list.options.listNodeName).first(), depth);
            return data;
        },

        serialise: function()
        {
            return this.serialize();
        },

        reset: function()
        {
            this.mouse = {
                offsetX   : 0,
                offsetY   : 0,
                startX    : 0,
                startY    : 0,
                lastX     : 0,
                lastY     : 0,
                nowX      : 0,
                nowY      : 0,
                distX     : 0,
                distY     : 0,
                dirAx     : 0,
                dirX      : 0,
                dirY      : 0,
                lastDirX  : 0,
                lastDirY  : 0,
                distAxX   : 0,
                distAxY   : 0
            };
            this.isTouch    = false;
            this.moving     = false;
            this.dragEl     = null;
            this.dragRootEl = null;
            this.dragDepth  = 0;
            this.hasNewRoot = false;
            this.pointEl    = null;
        },

        expandItem: function(li)
        {
            li.removeClass(this.options.collapsedClass);
            li.children('[data-action="expand"]').hide();
            li.children('[data-action="collapse"]').show();
            li.children(this.options.listNodeName).show();
        },

        collapseItem: function(li)
        {
            var lists = li.children(this.options.listNodeName);
            if (lists.length) {
                li.addClass(this.options.collapsedClass);
                li.children('[data-action="collapse"]').hide();
                li.children('[data-action="expand"]').show();
                li.children(this.options.listNodeName).hide();
            }
        },

        expandAll: function()
        {
            var list = this;
            list.el.find(list.options.itemNodeName).each(function() {
                list.expandItem($(this));
            });
        },

        collapseAll: function()
        {
            var list = this;
            list.el.find(list.options.itemNodeName).each(function() {
                list.collapseItem($(this));
            });
        },

        setParent: function(li)
        {
            if (li.children(this.options.listNodeName).length) {
                li.prepend($(this.options.expandBtnHTML));
                li.prepend($(this.options.collapseBtnHTML));
            }
            li.children('[data-action="expand"]').hide();
        },

        unsetParent: function(li)
        {
            li.removeClass(this.options.collapsedClass);
            li.children('[data-action]').remove();
            li.children(this.options.listNodeName).remove();
        },

        dragStart: function(e)
        {
            var mouse    = this.mouse,
                target   = $(e.target),
                dragItem = target.closest(this.options.itemNodeName);

            this.placeEl.css('height', dragItem.height());

            mouse.offsetX = e.offsetX !== undefined ? e.offsetX : e.pageX - target.offset().left;
            mouse.offsetY = e.offsetY !== undefined ? e.offsetY : e.pageY - target.offset().top;
            mouse.startX = mouse.lastX = e.pageX;
            mouse.startY = mouse.lastY = e.pageY;

            this.dragRootEl = this.el;

            this.dragEl = $(document.createElement(this.options.listNodeName)).addClass(this.options.listClass + ' ' + this.options.dragClass);
            this.dragEl.css('width', dragItem.width());

            dragItem.after(this.placeEl);
            dragItem[0].parentNode.removeChild(dragItem[0]);
            dragItem.appendTo(this.dragEl);

            $(document.body).append(this.dragEl);
            this.dragEl.css({
                'left' : e.pageX - mouse.offsetX,
                'top'  : e.pageY - mouse.offsetY
            });
            // total depth of dragging item
            var i, depth,
                items = this.dragEl.find(this.options.itemNodeName);
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                depth = $(items[i]).parents(this.options.listNodeName).length;
                if (depth > this.dragDepth) {
                    this.dragDepth = depth;
                }
            }
        },

        dragStop: function(e)
        {
            var el = this.dragEl.children(this.options.itemNodeName).first();
            el[0].parentNode.removeChild(el[0]);
            this.placeEl.replaceWith(el);

            this.dragEl.remove();
            this.el.trigger('change');
            if (this.hasNewRoot) {
                this.dragRootEl.trigger('change');
            }
            this.reset();
        },

        dragMove: function(e)
        {
            var list, parent, prev, next, depth,
                opt   = this.options,
                mouse = this.mouse;

            this.dragEl.css({
                'left' : e.pageX - mouse.offsetX,
                'top'  : e.pageY - mouse.offsetY
            });

            // mouse position last events
            mouse.lastX = mouse.nowX;
            mouse.lastY = mouse.nowY;
            // mouse position this events
            mouse.nowX  = e.pageX;
            mouse.nowY  = e.pageY;
            // distance mouse moved between events
            mouse.distX = mouse.nowX - mouse.lastX;
            mouse.distY = mouse.nowY - mouse.lastY;
            // direction mouse was moving
            mouse.lastDirX = mouse.dirX;
            mouse.lastDirY = mouse.dirY;
            // direction mouse is now moving (on both axis)
            mouse.dirX = mouse.distX === 0 ? 0 : mouse.distX > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            mouse.dirY = mouse.distY === 0 ? 0 : mouse.distY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            // axis mouse is now moving on
            var newAx   = Math.abs(mouse.distX) > Math.abs(mouse.distY) ? 1 : 0;

            // do nothing on first move
            if (!mouse.moving) {
                mouse.dirAx  = newAx;
                mouse.moving = true;
                return;
            }

            // calc distance moved on this axis (and direction)
            if (mouse.dirAx !== newAx) {
                mouse.distAxX = 0;
                mouse.distAxY = 0;
            } else {
                mouse.distAxX += Math.abs(mouse.distX);
                if (mouse.dirX !== 0 && mouse.dirX !== mouse.lastDirX) {
                    mouse.distAxX = 0;
                }
                mouse.distAxY += Math.abs(mouse.distY);
                if (mouse.dirY !== 0 && mouse.dirY !== mouse.lastDirY) {
                    mouse.distAxY = 0;
                }
            }
            mouse.dirAx = newAx;

            /**
             * move horizontal
             */
            if (mouse.dirAx && mouse.distAxX >= opt.threshold) {
                // reset move distance on x-axis for new phase
                mouse.distAxX = 0;
                prev = this.placeEl.prev(opt.itemNodeName);
                // increase horizontal level if previous sibling exists and is not collapsed
                if (mouse.distX > 0 && prev.length && !prev.hasClass(opt.collapsedClass)) {
                    // cannot increase level when item above is collapsed
                    list = prev.find(opt.listNodeName).last();
                    // check if depth limit has reached
                    depth = this.placeEl.parents(opt.listNodeName).length;
                    if (depth + this.dragDepth <= opt.maxDepth) {
                        // create new sub-level if one doesn't exist
                        if (!list.length) {
                            list = $('<' + opt.listNodeName + '/>').addClass(opt.listClass);
                            list.append(this.placeEl);
                            prev.append(list);
                            this.setParent(prev);
                        } else {
                            // else append to next level up
                            list = prev.children(opt.listNodeName).last();
                            list.append(this.placeEl);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // decrease horizontal level
                if (mouse.distX < 0) {
                    // we can't decrease a level if an item preceeds the current one
                    next = this.placeEl.next(opt.itemNodeName);
                    if (!next.length) {
                        parent = this.placeEl.parent();
                        this.placeEl.closest(opt.itemNodeName).after(this.placeEl);
                        if (!parent.children().length) {
                            this.unsetParent(parent.parent());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var isEmpty = false;

            // find list item under cursor
            if (!hasPointerEvents) {
                this.dragEl[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            this.pointEl = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX - document.body.scrollLeft, e.pageY - (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop)));
            if (!hasPointerEvents) {
                this.dragEl[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
            if (this.pointEl.hasClass(opt.handleClass)) {
                this.pointEl = this.pointEl.parent(opt.itemNodeName);
            }
            if (this.pointEl.hasClass(opt.emptyClass)) {
                isEmpty = true;
            }
            else if (!this.pointEl.length || !this.pointEl.hasClass(opt.itemClass)) {
                return;
            }

            // find parent list of item under cursor
            var pointElRoot = this.pointEl.closest('.' + opt.rootClass),
                isNewRoot   = this.dragRootEl.data('nestable-id') !== pointElRoot.data('nestable-id');

            /**
             * move vertical
             */
            if (!mouse.dirAx || isNewRoot || isEmpty) {
                // check if groups match if dragging over new root
                if (isNewRoot && opt.group !== pointElRoot.data('nestable-group')) {
                    return;
                }
                // check depth limit
                depth = this.dragDepth - 1 + this.pointEl.parents(opt.listNodeName).length;
                if (depth > opt.maxDepth) {
                    return;
                }
                var before = e.pageY < (this.pointEl.offset().top + this.pointEl.height() / 2);
                    parent = this.placeEl.parent();
                // if empty create new list to replace empty placeholder
                if (isEmpty) {
                    list = $(document.createElement(opt.listNodeName)).addClass(opt.listClass);
                    list.append(this.placeEl);
                    this.pointEl.replaceWith(list);
                }
                else if (before) {
                    this.pointEl.before(this.placeEl);
                }
                else {
                    this.pointEl.after(this.placeEl);
                }
                if (!parent.children().length) {
                    this.unsetParent(parent.parent());
                }
                if (!this.dragRootEl.find(opt.itemNodeName).length) {
                    this.dragRootEl.append('<div class="' + opt.emptyClass + '"/>');
                }
                // parent root list has changed
                if (isNewRoot) {
                    this.dragRootEl = pointElRoot;
                    this.hasNewRoot = this.el[0] !== this.dragRootEl[0];
                }
            }
        }

    };

    $.fn.nestable = function(params)
    {
        var lists  = this,
            retval = this;

        lists.each(function()
        {
            var plugin = $(this).data("nestable");

            if (!plugin) {
                $(this).data("nestable", new Plugin(this, params));
                $(this).data("nestable-id", new Date().getTime());
            } else {
                if (typeof params === 'string' && typeof plugin[params] === 'function') {
                    retval = plugin[params]();
                }
            }
        });

        return retval || lists;
    };

})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto, window, document);
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `.on('click', ...`

Comment: It makes sense but doesn't work either

Comment: Then, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: working on it now

Comment: @raul.vila it is edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the better way to achieve what I need (i.e get access to the element I'm clicking on) is by adding the following code:

```
$("div")
    .mousedown(function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, the only thing I had to add is `Event.stopPropagation();` inside the click handler function to avoid the event to be fired twice when clicking on 2nd level items (`Item 4` and `Item 5` in your example):

```js
$('.dd').nestable('');

$('.dd-item').on('click', function(Event) {
  console.log(Event.target);
  Event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.cf:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }
* html .cf { zoom: 1; }
*:first-child+html .cf { zoom: 1; }

/*NESTABLE*/
.dd { position: relative; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; max-width: 600px; list-style: none; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px; }

.dd-list { display: block; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.dd-list .dd-list { padding-left: 30px; }
.dd-collapsed .dd-list { display: none; }

.dd-item,
.dd-empty,
.dd-placeholder { display: block; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height: 20px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px; }

.dd-handle { display: block; height: 30px; margin: 5px 0; padding: 5px 10px; color: #333; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fafafa;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 0%, #eee 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 0%, #eee 100%);
    background:         linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 0%, #eee 100%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dd-handle:hover { color: #2ea8e5; background: #fff; }

.dd-item > button { display: block; position: relative; cursor: pointer; float: left; width: 25px; height: 20px; margin: 5px 0; padding: 0; text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; border: 0; background: transparent; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; }
.dd-item > button:before { content: '+'; display: block; position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align: center; text-indent: 0; }
.dd-item > button[data-action="collapse"]:before { content: '-'; }
.button_make_container > .dd_item

.dd-placeholder,
.dd-empty { margin: 5px 0; padding: 0; min-height: 30px; background: #f2fbff; border: 1px dashed #b6bcbf; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; }
.dd-empty { border: 1px dashed #bbb; min-height: 100px; background-color: #e5e5e5;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff),
                      -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff),
                         -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff),
                              linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #fff 75%, #fff);
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px;
}

.dd-dragel { position: absolute; pointer-events: none; z-index: 9999; }
.dd-dragel > .dd-item .dd-handle { margin-top: 0; }
.dd-dragel .dd-handle {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            box-shadow: 2px 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

#button_make_container {
   border: 1px outset blue;
   background-color: lightBlue;
   float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Nestable/2012-10-15/jquery.nestable.min.js"></script>

<div class="dd">
  <ul class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
      <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
      <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="apples">
      <div class="dd-handle">Apples</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="oranges">
      <div class="dd-handle">Oranges</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="bananas">
      <div class="dd-handle">Bananas</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="strawberries">
      <div class="dd-handle">Strawberries</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
      <div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div>
      <ul class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
          <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="5">
          <div class="dd-handle">Item 5</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is working? I did the changes, but I can't see any difference.

Comment: The code (both versions: yours and mine) is executing `console.log(Event.target);`, so you should look at the console. Are you expecting an `alert` or something like this?

Comment: Console is fine. That's weird, I'm running but I can't see anything printed on console screen :(

Comment: Did you run the snippet in my answer? (there is a blue button under the code which says "Run code snippet"), when you click any element, you should see a message with that element.

Comment: That's so weird. I ran it on firefox and chrome, but I can't see any message when clicking on the elements... :(

Comment: I'm still not sure when you are talking about your code or my snippet :(. If you're talking about your code: don't you see any error message? If you're talking about the snippet: that's weird.

Comment: Yes, it is the snippet. I know it is weird. I am sorry about that. The code does not show any changes as well.

Comment: What message I'm supposed to see?

Comment: It totally makes sense. That's what I'm expecting to see - have absolutely no idea what is going wrong

Comment: So I think you can discard code bugs :P... just some random ideas: do you have a script blocker (noscript)? my code is using cdn's for jquery and nestable, maybe you're connection is blocking them? ... IDK :(

Comment: I'll try to use the cdns instead of the local files

Comment: A simple vote to the answer will be welcome if it has helped you ^_^